# Route for single post with OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, routes, octobercms

I have created route to show all posts on my page like this:

```
Route::get('posts', function() {
  $posts = Post::with(['image','category'])->get();
  return $posts;
});
```

How do I create route to show just single post based on its ID?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you try pass parameter with route:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Route::get('posts/{id}', function($id) {
    $posts = Post::with(['image','category'])->where('id', $id)->get();
    return $posts;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with pass id parameter in route:

```
Route::get('posts/{id}', function($id) {
    $posts = Post::with(['image','category'])->where('id', $id)->get();
    return $posts;
});
```